# Probability notation

Tags: math, boolean, probability, notation, probability-theory

I want to ask you about the notation in probability.

I know that

> P(A | B) = the conditional probability that event A occurs given that
>   event B has occurred already

But I cannot find what A,B or in my case P(A|B,C). I suggest it means "the conditional probability that event A occurs given that B and C BOTH occurred already"

I don't know what the comma means.

Can you help me ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are basically correct.

P(A| B) is the probability of A *given* B.
P(A| B, C) is the probability of A *given* (B and C).

You could just as easily write it as P(A| B ∧ C) but it is notational convention to use a comma.
Think of everything after the vertical bar as a list of the given things, separated by commas.

(And note that the vertical bar is a *very* high precedence operator, so to speak.)

Comment: And is there a notation for "the probability of B or C, givven that A happened": P(A|[B or C]), not P(A,[B and C]) - just curious

Comment: "The probability of *B* or *C*, given *A*" is denoted P(*B* ∨ *C* | *A*).

Comment: Isn't it lower order of precedence, since you apply the ANDs for the whole list before you apply the given-bar?

Comment: @dekuShrub you are correct, the author of the answer uses the words "high precedence" in the wrong way here. I think what he actually means is "giving the expression structure on a higher level than the commas", which basically means it's evaluated later than the commas, hence it has lower precedence, not higher precedence.

Comment: @Novak can you also give an example with many more variables and tell what it means, e.g. P(A, B, C, D, E | F, G, H, I, J, K)? I think it gets clearer then.

Answer (score 1):

This is according to Bayes rule

P(C|A,B) = P(A,B|C).P(C) / P(A,B)